# ¿Cómo recuperar un solo registro y mostrarlo con PHP y MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

Buenas noches a toda la comunidad.
Esta es mi primera pregunta y espero hacerlo de la manera correcta.
Estoy trabajando en una aplicación PHP - MYSQL, hasta el momento todo iba de manera correcta hasta que trabaje con una consulta que tiene que devolver un solo registro en base a un ID que el usuario envía desde otra pagina. La variable ID se recibe y captura sin problema, al realizar la comprobación de conexión a la BD no se muestra problema, al realizar la consulta y comprobar si se ejecuto de manera correcta tampoco muestra error, el problema viene cuando quiero capturar los datos de la consulta a un array asociativo y desplegar los datos en la página con el siguiente código:

```
    $query="SELECT Id_Almacenista AS Codigo,
                            Nombre_Almacenista AS Nombre,
                            Apellidos_Almacenista AS Apellidos,
                            Alias_Almacenista AS Alias 
                            FROM Almacenistas 
                            WHERE Id_Almacenista='$cod_alm'";
            if (!$datos=$mysqli->query($query)) {
                echo "<p>¡Lo sentimos el sitio est&aacute; experimentando problemas!</p>";
                #el siguiente segmento muestra el error en caso de que lo hubiera, no mostrar en productivo
                echo "Error: la ejecucion de la consulta fallo debido a; \n";
                echo "Consulta: " . $query . "\n";
                echo "errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
                echo "error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
            }
            if ($datos->num_rows===0) {
                echo "<p>¡Lo sentimos la consulta no encontro coincidencia para el ID: " .$cod_alm . "!</p>";
            }
            $fila=$datos->fetch_assoc();
            echo "<p>Est&aacute;s seguro de querer <strong>eliminar</strong> el siguiente registro:</p>";
            echo "ID: " . $fila['Codigo'] . "<br>";
            echo "Nombre: " . $fila['Nombre'] . "<br>";
            echo "Apellidos: " . $fila['Apellidos'] . "<br>";
            echo "Alias: " . $fila['Alias'] . "<br>";
```

El error que arroja la página al ejecutarla es:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in...\InventarioSL\php\logica\eliminar_alm.php on line xx

Ya Google e investigue todo lo que pude, he rehecho la página varias veces pero el error prosigue, y trato de entender que estoy haciendo mal.
Agradezco de antemano el apoyo que me puedan brindar.
Saludos cordiales.
Nota: La consulta se ejecuta sin problemas en MYSQL WORKBENCH

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código en *"line xx"*?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de la siguiente forma:

```
$query="
    SELECT
        Id_Almacenista AS Codigo,
        Nombre_Almacenista AS Nombre,
        Apellidos_Almacenista AS Apellidos,
        Alias_Almacenista AS Alias 
    FROM
        Almacenistas 
    WHERE
        Id_Almacenista='$cod_alm'
    LIMIT 1
";

if( $result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    if( $row = $result->fetch_array() ){
        echo "Los datos obtenidos son: <br />";
        echo "Id_Almacenista = ".$row->Codigo."<br />";
        echo "Nombre_Almacenista = ".$row->Nombre."<br />";
        echo "Alias_Almacenista = ".$row->Alias."<br />";
    }else{
        echo "El registro no se ha encontrado.";
    }
}else{
    echo "No se pudo realizar la consulta. Error: (#".$mysqli->errno.") ".$mysqli->error;
}
```

De todos modos te sugiero un par de cosas:

1. No hacer la consulta colocando la variable $cod_alm directamente en ella, ya que de ese modo es susceptible de un ataque por inyección. Es mejor hacerla mediante "prepared statements".
2. Mientras estés en fase de desarrollo, puedes añadir estas líneas al comienzo de tu fichero PHP, de forma que te muestre todos los errores y warnings posibles. En producción, coméntalas o elimínalas para no dar ideas a los malos, jejeje.

   ```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ```

Espero que te sirva.

NOTA: No he lanzado el código, pues no me he creado una tabla con tus datos para realizar la prueba. Coméntame si te sale algún error y lo corregimos.

Un saludo!

Comment: agradezco tu pronta respuesta, realice los cambios que me sugieres pero el problema persiste. Agregue las líneas que sugieres para mostrar los warnings y errores, pero al ejecutar la página no muestra ninguno. Me regresa el else que dice que el registro no fue encontrado. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que efectivamente existe un registro en la tabla con el id que estás buscando? Asegúrate de poner el valor correcto en $cod_alm

Comment: Los snippets están diseñados para publicar ejemplos con HTML/CSS/JavaScript que pueden ejecutarse directamente en el navegador. No soportan otros lenguajes, como PHP. Si das clic en "ejecutar" en uno de tus snippets, lo que vas a ver es, no el resultado de la ejecución en PHP, sino probablemente mensajes de error, texto plano o nada.

Comment: Hola. Imagino que está usando el ejemplo que le puse en si server de pruebas ya que dice que le devuelve el error de que el registro no se ha encontrado. Creo que el problema es que, o bien no ha cargado el id correctamente en la variable $cod_alm o que el valor que le asigna no corresponde a ningún registro en su tabla (ya que eso es precisamente lo que muestra ese mensaje, que la consulta se realizó sin errores pero devolvión un conjunto vacío de filas)

Comment: Ops, leí mal tu comentario,@jachguate. Lo siento. Acabo de editar la respuesta para marcar los fragmentos de código como tales, en vez de como snippets. Muchas gracias por tu comentario!! Un saludo!

Comment: Buenas tardes @Hnry23, perdón por la tardanza en la respuesta. Agradezco todo su apoyo y respuestas, de acuerdo con sus consejos revise al dedillo todas y cada una de las líneas de código involucradas para ver que se enviasen de manera correcta. El error radicaba en la página que envía la variable por GET, ya que tenía un carácter de espacio sobrante y que la variable que lo recibía tomaba y la consulta en consecuencia no encontraba coincidencia alguna. Reitero nuevamente mi agradecimiento.

Comment: @jachguate, agradezco los comentarios. Saludos.